# WCF single instance of service for VB (COM) client

Tags: c#, wcf, vb6

I created a WCF service, and want to be used by multiple VB clients.

I need only a single instance of the service, even if multiple clients start, use it, or stop.

But the result seems to be against my expectation.
My code is:

WCF service:

```
namespace xComm
{
    [ServiceBehavior(
        InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
            ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class SvcACS : ISvcACS
    {
        private int m_nCounter = 0;

        public int CounterUp()
        {
            m_nCounter++;
            return m_nCounter;
        }
        public int CounterGet()
        {
            return m_nCounter;
        }

    }
}
```

After building the WCF service, I can use it by COM reference from VB application, as the following one, a simple form application calling CountUp method and checking return value:

```
Option Explicit

Dim svcAcs As xComm.ISvcACS

Private Sub btnCmd_Click(Index As Integer)
    Dim nW1 As Integer
    
    nW1 = svcAcs.CounterUp()
    lblCounter.Caption = CStr(nW1)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set svcAcs = New xComm.svcAcs                   
End Sub
```

I started for example 2 VB clients and press the btnCmd button respectively.
What I want is:

1. client 1's btnCmd is clicked: client 1's lblCount shows 1
2. client 2's btnCmd is clicked: client 2's lblCount shows 2
3. client 1's btnCmd is clicked: client 1's lblCount shows 3
   ...

But the result turned out that clients are serviced independently, instead of by using a single instance of service, which the counter would have been shared.

I have used InstanceContextMode.Single, is this not enough?

Thanks in advance.

Ting

some new findings(2022/7/26):

Instead of using COM reference directly, I tried the following VB code:

```
    Dim Client As New MSSOAPLib30.SoapClient30
    
    
    Set Client = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")    'xcomm.svcACS")
    Call Client.mssoapinit("http://localhost:8733/SvcACS?wsdl")
                    'localhost:8733/SvcACS" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    MsgBox (Client.CounterUp())
```

The result shows that several VB application instances consume a same service instance.

And I also tested C# clients by using SvcUtilexe generated client code, which shows the same result.

But in both the cases, changing InstanceContextMode to PerCall or PerSession makes not difference.

I guess, maybe it is the behavior of self hosting service, in which the active service works for all.

But still I dont understand how COM interface works. Seemingly by using COM interface, each time, a new service instance is created.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a speculation on my part, but [the Instancing article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/instancing) notes, that

> Single: A single instance of the service class handles all client
> requests *for the lifetime of **the** application*.

*(Emphasis mine)*

Which to me sounds that because you are using **two** applications, each creating its own instance of the service, you experience the expected behavior. So I assume you need to persist & restore the return value between calls and share it between the service instances.

Comment: but, how the service knows its client application's life time? And also, I changed InstanceContextMode.Single to PerCall, and got the same results.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the documentation, there are a few things to note:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/de41d6/instance-context-mode-in-wcf/

> Note: BasicHttpBinding doesn't support sessions.
> If the binding in a WCF service is set to basichttpbinding then per session
> mode will not work and the service will be considered to be per call.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode?view=netframework-4.8

> The Single value specifies that a single InstanceContext object should
> be used for the lifetime of the service. Several caveats are
> associated with the Single value:
>
> - If the ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode value is set to    Single, your service can only process one message at a time unless you also set the ConcurrencyMode value to ConcurrencyMode.Multiple.
> - For singleton lifetime behavior (for example, if the host application    calls the ServiceHost.ServiceHost constructor and
>   passes an object to    use as the service), the service class must set
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode to Single, or an exception is thrown when the service host is opened.